# Logistic Regression Limitations

Tags: logistic, cart, boosting

I have been given a problem where I need to create an algorithm to predict a binary variable with 10 coefficients. I have no idea what the relationship is between those coefficients, but I know that there is one. This relationship is likely very complicated. The correct algorithm will likely not only look at each variable as an individual, but how these variables relate to each other: Eg.

if (x > y and z < 0) OR (w < v AND a < b AND c > 5), return 0.

Else, if (insert criteria similar to one above), return 1

It's become pretty clear to me that a human can't really solve this task without using a tedious and excessive amount of guessing and testing. I have decided to use a logistic regression for this task, and I've already programmed a pretty straightforward model using turicreate to do this.

My question is: with enough data, can logistic regression models learn to accurately predict variables by assessing the relationship between coefficients? Is there a better way to do this, such as a decision tree / random forest / boosted tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you invent clever features as highly non-linear functions of $\{X_1,X_2\}$, logistic regression will not be able to separate the two classes visualized below. Logistic regression will have to draw the boundary somewhere. Adding powers of $\{X_1,X_2\}$ will not help in this situation. You will need to know the nature of the two classes to introduce features based on the mod() function.

[image]

On the other hand, boosted trees and random forests will do the feature development for you. Automatically. Carefully.

Comment: +1. With the caveat that boosted trees and random forests need a lot of data.

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa Good point. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Will a decision tree work for this as well? If so, are they any more efficient in the amount of data that they need?

Comment: Though 1 classification tree could approximate the aforementioned relationship in theory, growing and pruning it would be difficult. Boosting and random forests would be better.